# How can I run Yast with X and ssh?

Tags: ssh, x11, opensuse, yast

I have an openSUSE machine which I log on to with ssh -X. I don't want to log in as root but I do want to run graphical Yast. Inside the ssh session sudo starts the console version of Yast. However, in Gnome or KDE it is possible to start Yast as a normal user and then give a root password in a window to run Yast as root.

How can I do that from my ssh session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in as "normal" user (using X11-forward), then `su - -c yast2`.

Comment: Ta. That worked.

Comment: what if I would like to use my password (sudo) not root password?

Comment: @mpapis should work via sudo, too, but I did not check. `sudo` is more common on Debian-based systems. You might have to force TTY-allocation to make it work in a single command via ssh.

Comment: `sudo` most likely has `env_reset` which means most of environment variables are lost, including `DISPLAY`, you would have to write it like `sudo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY yast2`, but this still does not work when `ssh -Y` is used as authentication to X server is lost with sudo, so any hints?

Answer (score 1):

X uses a variable called `DISPLAY` in order to determine where to send the "information" related to the display. When you use `ssh -X`, SSH creates a `DISPLAY` variable and X programs use that.

When you use `sudo`, it gives you a restricted environment. To avoid this, you could try the command:

```
sudo -E yast
```

This will run `yast` but preserve the environment.  This may or may not work depending on your `sudoers` settings, in particular `setenv` and the `SETENV` tag for commands (with the `ALL` command tag, `SETENV` is implied).

To just set `DISPLAY` (in case it doesn't transfer over), you could do this too:

```
sudo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY yast
```

This is subject to the same restrictions as the first command.

Comment: About the "-" sudo complains "-: command not found". Without the "-" both commands just start text-mode yast as root, not the X version.

Comment: That was a syntax error on my part (fixed above). I would try something like `sudo su -` and then `echo $DISPLAY` and see what it says. I might also try an X-only program to see what happens. If `DISPLAY` is set right and the access is good, it should work. You could try this sequence too: `xhost +; sudo -E yast` - that grants access to the display, but I don't think that's right.

Comment: I do wonder how Yast decides whether to display X or use the console.

Comment: yast2 automatically chooses based on modules loaded and on the `DISPLAY` variable; check the `DISPLAY` variable and make sure that the display works. It is possible to login with `ssh -X` and have the remote SSH deny X forwarding; so check `DISPLAY`. Also make sure that you have the X libraries loaded on the remote system; if they're not available, it won't work. You can affect the GUI that yast2 uses through a setting in `/etc/sysconfig/yast2`: `WANTED_GUI="gtk"` (or `qt`). If you have X available on the remote system, try `xclock` and `sudo xclock` to see if the display actually works.

Comment: X works for programs that run without sudo.  sudo xlogo
Error: Can't open display:

Comment: Are you making sure that `DISPLAY` is set after using `sudo`? Also check for `XAUTHORITY`; both will need to be set in your `sudo` environment. If `sudo` is stripping out these variables from your environment, then you'll have to set them by hand or configure `sudo` to not do this.